# alternate phrases for "Not well thought out"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I need a phrase or word that with the same meaning as the phrase "not well thought out."

I am writing a major term paper on war. I am currently just creating a mindmap (I use them in the same way as an outline, because I tend to overthink outlines). My thought is that "war is never well thought out," or perhaps "war is not very well thought out." (Actually, the latter of those should be removed, it sounds rather daft.)

Comment: It might be useful to say what is "not well thought out". Ill-considered, ill-planned, even hamfisted could fit, depending on context.

Comment: Certainly... 
I am writing a major term paper on war. I am currently just creating a mindmap (I use them in the same way as an outline, because I tend to overthink outlines). My thought is that "war is never well thought out," or perhaps "war is not very well thought out." (Actually, the latter of those should be removed, it sounds rather daft.)

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross I actually can't use hamfisted here, I have used it previously in the paper. I feel that using it again would detract from the paper.

Comment: _Unclear on the concept_ is the phrase I would use.

Comment: yes please do add little detail for it isn't clear what you are asking and no need to add details about delete it or flag it, it just makes you r question more lengthy and unpleasant.

Comment: @Raghav I have deleted the unneeded sections.

Comment: What did your dictionaries, thesauruses or even search engines offer?

“not well thought out” can be important, but has nothing to do with “war”.

Might it have been better to keep to yourself what you thought sounded “rather daft”?

Do you think - will your tutors will think - mind maps, outlines or your tendency to overthink could help your paper, or hurt it?

If you think “war is never well thought out" why not justify that… it could be true… instead of worrying about irrelevant “alternative phrases”?

How could that tiny detail help you write your own term paper?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you commented on a question that was 5 years old. While constructive criticism is welcome on StackExchange websites, and my verbosity at the time I asked the question was excessive, I feel that your comment is both unhelpful and antagonistic. This is something that appears pervasive throughout your comments on the site. I refer you to the Unacceptable Behavior section of the new [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct), and hope that you will contribute in such a way that embraces the open, kind, and respectful exchange of knowledge with the community.

Comment: Uh… thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed the dates there and I've no idea what drew my attention to it…

Did you find what you wanted? Did the paper work?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I did find what I was looking for at the time. It has been five years, but I believe I scored top marks. We all need counsel and correction from time to time, and I hope that mine will be impactful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *War is always ill-conceived* on for a fit.